Prisma items optional but make security weak
 // schema.prisma

 model Product {
 id           String          @id @default(uuid())
 storeId      String
 store        Store           @relation("StoreToProduct", fields: [storeId], 
 references: [id])
 categoryId   String 
 category     Category        @relation("CategoryToProduct", fields: [categoryId], 
 references: [id])
 name         String
 price        Decimal
 isFeatured   Boolean         @default(false)
 isArchived   Boolean         @default(false)
 sizeId       String?       
 size         Size?           @relation(fields: [sizeId], references: [id])
 colorId      String?       
 color        Color?          @relation(fields: [colorId], references: [id])
 brandId      String?       
 brand        Brand?          @relation(fields: [brandId], references: [id])
 images       Image[]
 saleItems    SaleItem[]
 createdAt    DateTime        @default(now())
 updatedAt    DateTime        @updatedAt

 @@index([storeId])
 @@index([categoryId])
 @@index([brandId])
 @@index([sizeId])
 @@index([colorId])
}

// product.form.tsx

"use client";

import { UseOrigin } from "@/hooks/use-origin";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Brand, Category, Color, Image, Product, Size } from "@prisma/client";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import * as z from "zod";

const formSchema = z.object({
 name: z.string().min(1),
 images: z.object({ url: z.string() }).array(),
 price: z.coerce.number().min(1),
 categoryId: z.string().min(1),
 colorId: z.string().min(1).optional(),
 sizeId: z.string().min(1).optional(),
 brandId: z.string().min(1).optional(),
 isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
 isArchived: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
});

interface ProductFormProps {
 initialData:
 | (Product & {
    images: Image[];
  })
 | null;
categories: Category[];
colors?: Color[];
sizes?: Size[];
brands?: Brand[];
}

type ProductFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

export const ProductForm: React.FC<ProductFormProps> = ({
 initialData,
 categories,
 brands,
 colors,
 sizes,
}) => {
 const params = useParams();
 const router = useRouter();
 const origin = UseOrigin();
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const form = useForm<ProductFormValues>({
 resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
 defaultValues: initialData
   ? {
      ...initialData,
      price: parseFloat(String(initialData?.price)),
      brandId: initialData.brandId || undefined,
      colorId: initialData.colorId || undefined,
      sizeId: initialData.sizeId || undefined,
    }
   : {
      name: "",
      images: [],
      price: 0,
      categoryId: "",
      colorId: undefined,
      sizeId: undefined,
      brandId: undefined,
      isFeatured: false,
      isArchived: false,
    },
 });

// color-form.tsx same as size-form.tsx and brand-form.tsx

const onDelete = async () => {
 try {
  setLoading(true);
  await axios.delete(`/api/${params.storeId}/colors/${params.colorId}`);
  router.refresh();
  router.push(`/${params.storeId}/colors`);
  toast.success("Color deleted.");
} catch (error) {
  toast.error("Make sure you removed all products using this color first");
} finally {
  setLoading(false);
  setOpen(false);
}
};

// cell-actions.tsx same for brand and size

 const onDelete = async () => {
  try {
   setLoading(true);
   await axios.delete(`/api/${params.storeId}/colors/${data.id}`);
   router.refresh();
   toast.success("Color deleted.");
  } catch (error) {
   toast.error("Make sure you removed all products using this color first");
  } finally {
   setLoading(false);
   setOpen(false);
 }
};

I am building an admin panel for e-commerce using Prisma, NextJS, and Supabase, and I want to make the product filters (brand, color, size, etc) optional when the admin creates a product. But the problem I am having is that once they are optional, the function that checks if the item (brand, size, color) is used in a product seems not to work. For example, I have a category item that is required, and whenever the user wants to delete it, he has to delete every product that uses that category first, then he can delete the category. I want the user to be unable to delete the filters before he deletes the products that use them first.

Use referential actions to specify at the database level what happens if a referenced record is deleted. In your case, you probably want onDelete: Restrict. This means that if a filter (Brand, Color, Size) tries to be deleted from the database, the delete operation is blocked so long as it is connected to a Product.
sizeId       String?
size         Size?           @relation(onDelete: Restrict, fields: [sizeId], references: [id])
colorId      String?       
color        Color?          @relation(onDelete: Restrict, fields: [colorId], references: [id])
brandId      String?       
brand        Brand?          @relation(onDelete: Restrict, fields: [brandId], references: [id])

